# How do I make a Cross-Domain Request in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, jquery, cross-domain

I am using the following jQuery AJAX call to access a SOAP Web Service:

```
jQuery.ajax({    
    url: url,    
    type: "GET",             
    dataType: "jsonp text",
    crossDomain :true,
    data:"i="+'a'+"&j="+'b',
    processData: false, 
    success: OnSuccess,       
    error: OnError      
});
```

This code works fine in IE but it get an empty response in Firefox. On further searching it seems Firefox does not allow cross domain requests by default, or it processes the header information differently.

My application is on `localhost:8081`, and the WebService I want to consume is on `localhost:8080`. Is there any way I can allow Firefox to make a cross domain request?

Comment: have you checked the output of firebug

Comment: ya, I checked, the response is ""

Answer (score 0):

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP_access_control

Answer (score 0):

ya, This issue is resolved after I installed CORS add-on for firefox. But is there any other way, I can set the parameters using JQuery-ajax code?

Answer (score 0):

you need send "Access-Control-####" headers same what in OPTIONS request response.